# Advice on how to monitor (micro)services?

Tags: service, spring-boot, monitoring, microservices, spring-boot-actuator

We are transitioning from building applications on monolith application servers, to more microservices oriented applications on Spring Boot. We will publish health information with SB Actuator through HTTP or JMX.

What are the options/best practices to monitor services, that will be around 30-50 in total? Thanks for your input!

Comment: Good monitoring is essential when you develop microservices. I guess to answer your question more specifically it would be good to know a little about your architecture. How are you doing service discovery, load balancing, etc.? Are you deploying these in a public cloud or in your own data center? Do you distribute your service instances across multiple physical machines and geographical regions?

Comment: We are not quite down to microservices level, somewhere between that and monolith. We do not have service discovery, we have a hardware load balancer, private VM datacenter, we distriute across multiple physical machines, but in one geographical region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing too much detail about your architecture and services, here are some suggestions that represent (a subset of) the strategies that have been proven in systems i've worked on in production. For this I am assuming you are using one container/VM per micro service:

- If your services are stateless (as they should be :-) and you have redundancy (as you should have :-) then you set up your load balancer to call your /health on each instance and if the health check fails then the load balancer should take the instance out of rotation. Depending on how tolerant your system is, you can set up various rules that define failure instead of just a single failure (e.g. 3 consecutive, etc.)
- On each instance run a Nagios agent that calls your health check (/health) on the localhost. If this fails, generate an alert that specifies which instance failed.
- You also want to ensure that a higher level alert is generated if none of your instances are healthy for a given service. You might be able to set this up in your load balancer or you can set up a monitor process outside the load balancer that calls your service periodically and if it does not get any response (i.e. none of the instances are responding) then it should sound all alarms. Hopefully this condition is never triggered in production because you dealt with the other alarms.
- Advanced: In a cloud environment you can connect the alarms with automatic scaling features. In that way, unhealthy instances are torn down and healthy ones are brought up automatically every time an instance of a service is deemed unhealthy by the monitoring system

Comment: Can you please provide some name of the tools that can help achieve what you described?